# Quelle est la différence entre « Tout en (gérondif) » et « En (gérondif) »?

Tags: grammaire

Quand on met « tout » avant le gérondif, la signification change-t-elle ?

Par exemple:

> Il travaille en chantant

Vs.

> Il travaille tout en chantant

Y a-t-il une différence ?

Comment: "Tout" dans ce sens est surtout utilisé pour des activités qui ne sont, à premier abord, pas très compatibles : "Écouter youtube tout en faisant autre chose sur son téléphone" (cet exemple fonctionne, car l'application youtube sur téléphone ne fonctionne normalement pas si ce n'est pas l'app en premier plan et ne permettant pas de faire autre chose sans une manipulation précise).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La construction "en + gérondif" indique parfois le moyen employé, et non la simple simultanéité.

"Tout en + gérondif" indique en revanche seulement une simultanéité et peut être employé pour clarifier ou mettre l'emphase sur le fait qu'il ne s'agit pas d'un moyen employé.

On dira par exemple

> J'ai appris l'anglais en voyageant à Londres (= j'ai appris l'anglais grâce à des voyages à Londres, indiquant le moyen d'apprentissage)
>
> J'ai appris l'espagnol tout en voyageant à Londres (= j'ai appris l'espagnol pendant que je voyageais à Londres, sans que le voyage y ait été pour quelque chose)

Cependant, quand le contexte est clair, "en + gérondif" n'indique pas forcément le moyen (comme dans l'exemple de la question). Dans ces cas-là, la différence est simplement une question d'emphase, la construction "tout en chantant" étant juste un peu plus longue.

Answer (score 1):

Le fait d'ajouter « tout » devant *en + gérondif* signale une opposition entre les deux actions, on pourrait dire :

> Il travaille quoique/alors que/bien qu'il chante en même temps.

Comment: Merci bien pour le vote négatif, une explication serait la bienvenue.

Comment: Je ne suis pas la personne qui a downvote, mais il y a plusieurs points négatifs. Par exemple, dans les 3 phrases proposées, l'ajout de "en même temps" rend la phrase beaucoup trop lourde, voire fausse.

Comment: @MorganFR: J'ai ajouté « en même temps » pour renforcer la notion d'opposition, (par ailleurs, c'est vrai que c'est beaucoup plus (trop) lourd mais c'est volontaire). Tu confonds « quoiqu'il » et « quoi qu'il ».

Comment: Pour moi l'opposition n'est pas systématique avec "tout en".

Comment: @SimonDéchamps En effet, ce n'est pas le fait d'ajouter "tout en" qui va montrer une opposition, mais bien que les deux actions sont à priori peu compatibles. "Il parle tout en marchant" ne possède aucune contradition, et ajouter "tout en" est même une erreur non pas de grammaire, mais de sens, tout comme la phrase de l'OP par exemple.

Comment: @Toto Si une partie de phrase n'est qu'un renforcement, un sous-entendu ou une précision, surtout si elle rend la phrase fausse, je te conseille de la mettre entre **parenthèses**, pour bien montrer qu'elle n'en fait normalement pas partie. Pour ce qui est du "quoique", le fait d'utiliser toutes ces barres obliques m'a fait ajouter des espaces inutiles, donc j'ai eu du mal à le lire.

Answer (score 0):

La forme "Tout + gérondif" peut avoir pour sémantique l'opposition dans certaine phrase :

> Tout en étant dévot, on n’en est pas moins homme.

Mais peut également signifier simplement la concomitance comme, je penses, dans l'exemple fourni. D'après [la source que j'utilise qui pourrait tenir lieu de réponse en elle même](http://discours.revues.org/8962?lang=en#tocto1n3) :

> Il existe des cas où l’apport de tout est pratiquement nul, ce qui rend identiques les formes du gérondif simple et de tout + gérondif